# How to get away with end of input error in Elm?

Tags: elm

I am learning Elm and after I did the tutorial I am starting e new application from scratch, but when I add a new HTML tag in my view I get an error.

My code:

```
module Main exposing (..)

import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)


main : Html a
main =
    span [ class "welcome-message" ] [ text "Hello, World!" ]
    , h1 [class "headline"] [text "Hello"]
```

Error:

```
Detected errors in 1 module.

-- SYNTAX PROBLEM ----------------------------------------------------- 

Main.elm I ran into something unexpected when parsing your code! 

10|     , h1 [class "headline"] [text "Hello"]         

^ I am looking for one of the following things:     
end of input     
whitespace
```

I am using Visual Studio Code on Windows 10.

My editor is configured to use LF and 4 spaces indentation.

I am using elm-reactor on PowerShell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is invalid Elm code: a comma can only go between elements of a list (or record). Also, you can't have two Html nodes at the top level, so you'll need to wrap them in a single element. In this case, you'll probably want to wrap the two in a `div [] []`:

```
main : Html a
main =
    div []
        [ span [ class "welcome-message" ] [ text "Hello, World!" ]
        , h1 [ class "headline" ] [ text "Hello" ]
        ]
```

Comment: Elm error messages tend to be some of the [best in the business](http://elm-lang.org/blog/compilers-as-assistants#improved-error-messages)

Comment: @JúlioCampos, I've posted this example to Elm's Error Message Catalog, so they can try to improve the message in scenarios like this. https://github.com/elm/error-message-catalog/issues/261